# Function names case sensitivity in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I'm learning the syntax of Google BigQuery, and currently, I'm reading documentation regarding identifiers and case sensitivity. I'm focused on standard SQL syntax of BigQuery.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#case_sensitivity) says:

> BigQuery follows these rules for case sensitivity:
>   **Category** | **Case Sensitive?**
>   Function names |    No

But when I running the following statements in [Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery):

```
#standardSQL  
create function cs_test.function_a (x int64, y int64) as (x*y);
create function cs_test.function_A (x int64, y int64) as (x-y);
select cs_test.function_a(5,6); -- 30
select cs_test.function_A(5,6); -- -1
```

two functions are created and different results are provided as a result of select statements.

At the same time if I run the following statements I get an error, which says that the function is not found:

```
create function cs_test.function_b (x int64, y int64) as (x+y);
select cs_test.function_B(5,6); -- NOK
```

Is the function name case insensitive in Google BigQuery? From the code snippets provided above it seems to be case sensitive.

Thank you.

Comment: function name IS case sensitive in Google BigQuery!

Comment: The documentation should be updated ... the "function name" in that table means "built-in functions", like CONCAT can be used as Concat() or conCAT(), while user-defined functions are case sensitive.

Comment: Documentation updated, thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've found is correct. [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#case_sensitivity) has been updated to reflect it:

```
| Category                    | Case Sensitive? |
| Built-in Function names     | No              |    
| User-Defined Function names | Yes             |
```